# What is causing a formula parse error in my setFormula function in Google Sheets, and how can I fix it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Formula parse error after “setformula” in google sheets

Hy guys, I have a problem when using a basic setFormula in appScript...
I get a Formula parse error no matter what.

Here's the extract of my code :
spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=vlookup(B3;Dossards!$B$2:$C$21;2;FAUX)');

[formula parse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cab8A.jpg)
[formula parse error w french formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQbtH.jpg)

What am I missing? Why doesn't it work???
I have something like 200 files in which I need to copy paste this formula. This is really a burden...
Help will be highly appreciated!
Rgds, Sarah

The formula gets correct in the formula bar but it won't work until I copy the formula, clear the cell and paste the formula in the cell and hit enter, all this being done manually. I tried with the French formula recherchev instead of vlookup: it doesn't work either. I tried to add a spreadsheetApp.flush : won't work either.[manual copy paste formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZLMn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, i found the problem. My formula "in English" was not correctly written as I mixed french and English (lol)
I had : vlookup(B3;Dossards!$B$2:$C$21;2;FAUX)
instead of : vlookup(B3;Dossards!$B$2:$C$21;2;FALSE)
Now it works !!!
Rgds